# Тот же элемент

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте, у меня такая проблема:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#elem').html($(this).html()+'*')  
});
```

Надеюсь, вы по коду поймёте мой вопрос. Как сделать, чтобы оно работало?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#elem').html(function(index, value) {
        return value + '*';
    });
});
```